# Mock the dependent microservices for testing the performance of another microservice

Tags: spring-boot, performance-testing, microservices, jhipster-registry

I am working on setting up the environment for testing the performance of a microservice A.This microservice A has dependency to another micro service B.Both the microservices are registered in JHipster Registry and Rippon client is used for communicating between microservices(A & B).How do I mock the dependent micro service so that I don't need to hit that real microservice B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options, you achieving this :

1. [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/)
2. [RESTAssured](http://rest-assured.io/)
3. [MockMvc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)
4. [MockRestServer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html)